# Vbs that writes to a file then outputs only certain text from that file

Tags: vbscript

I need to create a log file (test.log) that gets written to after every step of this script with a time stamp and action performed.

I also need to create a text file (test_input.txt) that will write the following lines:
"Mary had a little lamb"
"Who lives in a pineapple under the sea"
"I tawt I taw a puddu cat"

Close the input file
Open the text file for reading
Read each line and write only the line associated with a sponge (line 2) determined by a conditional statement (if/end if)
Close the text file 
Close the log

Comment: OK. Go right ahead and do so. We'll wait.

Comment: All methods you need are in this MSDN: [FileSystemObject Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tkce7xa(v=vs.84).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do your homework yourself, maybe you'll learn something from it (that is the purpose of homework, isn't it?)

You can also try to figure out what this code is doing that is fulfilling your requirements, you'll learn certainly something from it:

```
Set al = createobject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
for each f in array("Mary had a little lamb", "Who lives in a pineapple under the sea", "I tawt I taw a puddu cat")
    for each l in filter(split(CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject").OpenTextFile("c:\temp\in.txt", 1).readall, vbNewLine), f)
        if not isEmpty(l) then al.add l
    next
next
CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject").OpenTextFile("G:\temp\out.txt", 2, true).write join(al.ToArray(), vbNewLine)
```